# C++ macros preventing Intellisense

Tags: c++

I have an issue with C++ macros. So I have this two Macros to help with OpenGL error handling. I have to basically wrap this Macro with any OpenGL function I attempt to call. The problem is that this `GLCall` macro prevents intellisense for anything I attempt to write below it. Anyone know what the issue might be? intellisense works perfectly **above** any `GLCall()` line by the way.

> the code

`#define ASSERT(x) if(!(x))__debugbreak();`

`#define GLCall(x) GLClearError(); x; ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__));`

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like the double semicolons? That's just a wild guess though. It's worth noting that Intellisense has a reputation of being finicky and showing errors even when the code itself has nothing wrong with it.  Have you tried compiling? Does compiling actually give you any errors?

Comment: @Chipster there are no errors at all. Everything compiles and builds well. There is just no intellisense.

Comment: What IDE are you using? And what version?

Comment: @Chipster you were basically correct, I was using the default c++ intellisense of Visual Studio which isn't very intelligent, but when I installed Visual Assist, everything just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studios default intellisense is not the most intelligent. All I did was install Visual Assist and everything worked well.